# Extract href from lazy-loading page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the `href` from the premier league website, however I cannot seem to get all the html links except from the first page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
#get the player index
table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table playerIndex'})
#<a> is where the href is stored
href_names = [link.get('href') for link in table.findAll('a')]
football_string = 'https://www.premierleague.com'
#concatenate to get the full html link
[football_string + str(x) for x in href_names]
```

Which only returns the first page - I have tried using `selenium` however the premier league website has an ad that appears every time it is used that prevents it from working. Any ideas on how to get all the `html` links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, the following approach should do it:

```
import requests

base = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/{}/'
link = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players'
payload = {
    'pageSize': '30',
    'compSeasons': '418',
    'altIds': 'true',
    'page': 0,
    'type': 'player',
    'id': '-1',
    'compSeasonId': '418'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['referer'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com/'
    s.headers['origin'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com'

    while True:
        res = s.get(link,params=payload)
        if not res.json()['content']:break
        for item in res.json()['content']:
            print(base.format(int(item['id'])))

        payload['page']+=1
```

Results are like (truncated):

```
https://www.premierleague.com/players/19970/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/13279/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/13286/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/10905/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/4852/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/4328/
https://www.premierleague.com/players/90665/
```

Comment: This works great! However could you give me a break down of what you have done? I would love to learn and implement this with full knowledge for future web-scraping

Comment: Open chrome dev tools, select `network` tab , and then select `All` tab. Now, scroll the page and you should get lots of links being produced under `Name`. Look for the links visible as `players?pageSize=30&compSeasons` and then click on it. You should get every single detail about the requests in it's right pane. Thanks.